# Help with display of error message

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm a newbie here. Maybe its a simple silly thing..but please help!

There is a custom object, say Student__c. There is a field called 'Account Number__c' in this object.
On record creation and update, I need to check if this 'Account number' is present in another object (Background Check__c). If present, I need to show a warning message (The orange colour one).
I'm using a trigger which calls an apex class and is checking the field using DML.

```
  trigger CheckPANstatus on Student_Master__c (Before Insert, Before Update) {
// Call Class and function 
   StudentPANcheckClass.checkBackground(Trigger.new);}
```

\

```
    public class StudentPANcheckClass{public void checkBackground(list <Student_Master__c> VarStudentList){
    
     for(Student_Master__c VarS :VarStudentList){
    
    // Check if Pan Number is not null. If not, check if PAN is present in Black listed candidate object
    
      //  if (Trigger.isInsert == True){
            if (String.isNotEmpty(VarS.PAN_Number__c)){
            
                Black_Listed_Candidate__c VarS2 =  New Black_Listed_Candidate__c();
                             
                
             if ([Select PAN__c FROM Black_Listed_Candidate__c WHERE PAN__c =: VarS.PAN_Number__c].size() >0){
                
                VarS2 = [Select PAN__c FROM Black_Listed_Candidate__c WHERE PAN__c =: VarS.PAN_Number__c]; 
                
                // If present, then update Background Status in Student Master and update phone nubmer in BLC  object
                
                           VarS.Background_Check_Status__c = 'Candidate is black-listed. Cannot hire!!';
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Candidate is black-listed. Cannot hire!!'));
                             
                        if (VarS.Phone_number__c.length() > 0){
                                 VarS2.Phone__c = VarS.Phone_number__c;
                               Update VarS2;
                         }
                        
               }
               else{
                           VarS.Background_Check_Status__c = 'Candidate is verified!!';
                         //  VarS.addError('Verified');
                         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Candidate verified!'));
                                    
                          
                  }
                  
            }
       }
    
 }
```

}

Also I created a VFP to just display the error message ( Using apex pageMessages)

```
  <apex:page standardController="Student_Master__c" > <apex:form ><apex:pageBLock >    <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages></apex:pageBLock></apex:form></apex:page>
```

I'm unable to pass error message from this trigger to VFP.
Is there a way to do so ? (I don't want to use `.addError()`)
Or, is there a way that I can directly call an apex class from my VFP without a button (Since VFP is only for display of error message, there is no button)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Why don't you want to use `.addError()`? [edit] your question to add those details.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers cannot show warnings. A trigger may execute in a wide variety of contexts, including API interactions, that don't have a UI context attached to them; a warning would not be meaningful there. A trigger can only do `addError()` to block a record from being inserted entirely.

If you need interactive warnings and page messages using `ApexPages.addMessage()`, you must implement them in your Visualforce controller - not a trigger. You can learn about writing Visualforce controllers in the [Visualforce Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals) module on Trailhead.

---

As a side note, Visualforce is a twice-obsolete framework. Consider using Lightning Web Components to build all new functionality and focusing learning on that framework.

Comment: Thank you David.  Yes, I can use Visualforce controllers. But here, I do not have any custom button, so I am not sure how to call the apex class from the standard layout buttons. Any information on that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In my custom object standard layout page, I have included a Visualforcepage, that has the standard controller (custom object) and extensions ( apex class).  The validation is done in apex class and i can use 'ApexPages.addMessage();'. But here, my confusion is the calling of this apex class.                                                                 How to call the apex class from the standard layout page? (Since there is only the standard 'Save' button; there is no custom button to call the apex class)                   Or, is it compulsary to add a custom button to call the apex class?

Comment: You can't. You would have to override the Edit action with a Visualforce page or Lightning component if you wish to display a warning. Errors don't require UI development because triggers can handle that.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I'll try to override the Edit action